# Why does running a PHP process in the background cause the whole site to hang?

Tags: nginx, background-process, php

I'm working on a PHP site which is running on nginx on Ubuntu 12. It can fire off long-running jobs in the background.

The idea is that the user submits a form, which starts a long job in another process (php_fpm should take care of this), and immediately a success/failure message is returned to the user if the job started or not.

Maybe this isn't the best way to do it, but this is what I'm doing:

```
`php $docroot/longjob.php $this->ID arg2 &> error_log &`;
```

($this->ID and arg2 are simple strings to configure the job.)

The job launches and runs properly, but the front-facing site hangs until the job is complete. Pages don't load and the server doesn't respond until the long job is complete. I was not expecting this. Why might this happen?

**Update:** So, I've been experimenting... unfortunately closing the session handler and trying the nohop command didn't stop the hanging. But it only hangs for me, on the machine I initiated the request from. I can log in from my phone and the site works properly, and it does for other users, too (phew). Any other thoughts as to why it would only hang on the machine that initiated the request?

If it matters, this is the default nginx error page that's displayed:

> The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
>
> Please try again later.

Comment: The built-in session save_handler will lock the session file until the process is finished and the next process will need to wait until the session file is unlocked. So if you are using sessions, you might need to call session_write_close before starting that long running job.

Comment: @AlexandruG. I am indeed using sessions. Never thought of that. I'll try that when I have a chance and report back!

Comment: @AlexandruG. Unfortunately, using `session_write_close() doesn't stop the waiting. It seems to only hang from the computer that I initiated the job on, though. So I wonder if there's still a sessions issue... or is it nginx/php-fpm doing something wonky...

Answer (score 1):

It happens because current PHP process waits for the command you executed to finish before it will continue. Like I said in a previous comment, close any session before starting that job, because PHP will lock the session file until that long running process will finish and the next process will need to wait until the session file is unlocked.

Regarding the method of execution of that command, I will do it with a nohup, something like this:

```
<?php
$cmd = "php $docroot/longjob.php $this->ID arg2";
exec("/usr/bin/nohup $cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

This way your `$cmd` will be started in background and the current process can continue his execution without caring about it.

Comment: I feel that's on the right track, and I've made that modification to my code, but unfortunately the site still hangs. See my update in my question though.

Comment: Did you checked the error_log ? Most likely you will find additional information about what is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this happened to me when, under nginx and PHP FPM, I had PHP run something like this:

```
exec("nohup ssh long-running command & >$logfile 2>&1");
```

I could see the processes in `ps axfw` like this:

```
[...]
18658 ?        S      0:00  \_ php-fpm: pool www
18734 ?        Z      0:00  |   \_ [sh] <defunct>
[...]
18737 ?        S      0:00 ssh long-running command
```

A bit of debugging showed that FPM was stuck waiting for the command:

```
% sudo strace -p 18658
Process 18658 attached
read(9, 

% sudo lsof -p 18658 | grep 9r
php5-fpm 18658  user    9r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 9332553 pipe

% sudo lsof -n | grep 9332553
php5-fpm  18658        user     9r     FIFO                0,8        0t0    9332553 pipe
ssh       18737        user     1w     FIFO                0,8        0t0    9332553 pipe
ssh       18737        user     6w     FIFO                0,8        0t0    9332553 pipe
```

That meant that two file descriptors of the child ssh somehow got left hooked to write over a pipe to the parent. They were 1 - standard output - and 6 - guessing that's remote command's standard output.

So it was clear that things went awry in trying to redirect that stdout to a log file. The solution was to use a more customary shell syntax:

```
 exec("nohup ssh long-running command >$logfile 2>&1 &");
```

That way, the shell forked by `exec()` redirected all output and put the ssh process in the background on the local machine, rather than (apparently) passing the ampersand to it.

Answer (score 0):

For a lengthy [Background] process I use this trick to my server.
Just wait a few seconds and then free to browse other pages as normal.

Hope someone will get it very helpful.

```
session_start();
isset($_SESSION['id']) or header('Location: ./index.html'.(
    isset($_REQUEST['redir'])? '?redir='.urlencode($_REQUEST['redir']):NULL
),TRUE)&exit;

$data= $_SESSION['userdata'];

/**The session need to be closed when running long process***/
session_write_close() & ignore_user_abort(TRUE);
set_time_limit(0);
```

Most of time I use AJAX asynchronous call to wait for response from this page.